# Add values ​to array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to add random numbers with array_push to an array in the field 'notes' => [] but I think I'm not doing it right since I do not see the random numbers stored in the array.

I am doing it in the following way:

```
$person1= [
    'name' => 'person1',
    'note' => []
];

$person2= [
    'name' => 'person2',
    'note' => []
];

$person3= [
    'name' => 'person3',
    'note' => []
];

$data=[$person1, $person2, $person3];
$_SESSION['data'] = $data;


function insertNumRandom(){

   $data = $_SESSION['data'];

   foreach ( $data as $student ) {

      array_push($student['note'], rand(0,10));
    }
}

function showNotes(){

    foreach ( $data as $student ) {

        echo implode($student['note']);
    }
}

showNotes(); // To show the notes but it shows nothing.
```

Comment: how are you calling the `insertNumRandom()` function ?

Comment: Why are you storing this in $_SESSION?

Answer (score 1):

You should change insertNumRandom like as below

```
function insertNumRandom(){
    $data = $_SESSION['data'];
    foreach ( $data as &$student ) {
        array_push($student['note'], rand(0,10));
    }
    $_SESSION['data'] = $data;
}
```

showNotes function

```
function showNotes(){
    $data = $_SESSION['data'];
    foreach ( $data as $student ) {
        echo implode($student['note']);
    }
}
```

and call insertNumRandom before showNotes.

```
insertNumRandom();
showNotes();
```

Comment: I don't mind code only examples, but it's not obvious what is different here, and why you've taken this approach.

Comment: Can you explain more your question? @Progrock

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Comment: (1) In the insertNumRandom function, should use $data = $_SESSION['data'] to get data in session, after that use & (&$student) to reassign the value to the $data variable and set data to session 
(2) if not using &(&$student) then array_push ($ student ['note'], rand (0.10)) cannot assign data to $data.
(3) In showNotes function, to show data we should get data from $_SESSION['data'].
(4) The end, we must be add random number before show it in $data variable.

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing the $data with the "as" keyword which creates a new object.

You should instead iterate through the object you already have.

```
function insertNumRandom(){
    $index = 0;
    for($index = 0; $index<sizeof($data['data']); $index++ ) {

      array_push($data[$index]['note'], rand(0,10));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this maybe, still not sure how you're calling the `insertNumRandom()` function

```
function showNotes($arr){

    foreach ( $arr as $student ) {

       var_dump(implode($student['note']));
    }
}

insertNumRandom();

showNotes($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a number of issues in your example.

1. First of all, the way you are using the $_SESSION object to pass some values to the function is not necessary, and not clean. You can either use `global $data` inside of the functions and they will suddenly have access to the $data variable from the parent scope. But even that is not very clean. I would suggest that you pass the data object by reference to the functions. That will make your function more portable and testable.
2. Your example is accessing the $student variable by value. All you need to do is to access it by reference by using the ampersand (&) in the foreach() like this `foreach ( $data as &$student ) { ... }`
3. I have noticed that you have never made a single call to `insertNumRandom()`
4. To have a better idea about what's in the arrays, I would suggest that you use a field separator for the implode() function and that you print a new line after imploding the array. I bet you will like the result.
5. Finally, just a word of advice ... array_push() lets you push one or more items in an array. But I personally use it only when I need to push multiple items in an array. For push just item new items, I use the short-hand `$myArray[] = "new item";`

So in practice, here is what your example will become ...

```
<?php
// Since you are not reusing $person1, $person2 and $person3 beyond the initialization
// phase, then let's keep things cleaner.
$data[] = [
  'name' => 'person1',
  'note' => []
];
$data[] = [
  'name' => 'person2',
  'note' => []
];
$data[] = [
  'name' => 'person3',
  'note' => []
];

/**
 * In this function signature, the & means that the argument is passed by reference.
 * That make it possible for the function to change the value of the argument.
 */
function insertNumRandom(&$theData) {
  // The foreach() also needs to use $student by reference so that we can modify it
  // by adding the random number to it.
  foreach($theData as &$student) {
    $student['note'][] = rand(0,10);
  }
}

/**
 * No need to pass $theData by reference because the function will not change its value.
 */
function showNotes($theData) {
  // Here, the foreach() is using student by value because we do not need to change it's value.
  foreach($theData as $student) {
    echo implode($student['note'], ', ') . "\n";
  }
}

// Inserting some random notes 3 times.
insertNumRandom($data);
insertNumRandom($data);
insertNumRandom($data);
showNotes($data); // To show the notes but it shows nothing.

?>
```